# Reg Ex to extract 2 texts from a variable

Tags: .net, regex, nintex-workflow

I need 2 separate regex (.net, c#) to extract values. I can't use grouping. Just need 2 separate Regex. I tried this `(?:^|(?:[.!?]\s))(\w+)` but it gives me `6;. Supplier`

For example

```
6. Supplier - Compressors, Drivers & Refrig. Units
```

1st regex will give me `Supplier`
2nd regex will give me `Compressors, Drivers & Refrig. Units`

example variables are (they are not together like this in my scenario). They are separate instance. The reason I need to separate Regex is to evaluate this value at different position in the code.

```
4. Cost/Estimating
6. Supplier - Minor Material: Specialty
6. Supplier - Pressure Vessels & Filters
6. Supplier - Pumps
6. Supplier - Minor Material: Valves
6. Supplier - Minor Material: Specialty
6. Supplier - Other Major Equipment
7. Manufacturing
8. Project Management
9. Order Release (OTR) - Commercial Documents
9. Order Release (OTR) - Hand-Off
```

Comment: Do you want just the suppliers and the products, ignoring the rest?

Comment: What's the expected output (in the correct format) and what's supposed to happen when there's no `-` separator such as line beginning with `4`?

Comment: `\d+\.\s*([^-\r\n]+?)(?:$|\s*-\s*(.*))`?

Comment: one regex to give me first word after number/period/space and 2nd regex to give me everything after the first -

Comment: The regex I posted should work for you^

Comment: (?:$|\s*-\s*(.*)) gives me everything including the - .  http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: \d+\.\s*([^-\r\n]+?) gives me 6. S

Comment: \d+\.\s*([^-\r\n]+?)(?:$|\s*-\s*(.*))? gives me entire line

Comment: @Fuji-H2O you're looking at the full match. Please see my answer below. You need to grab capture groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one regex with grouping:

```
    string myString = "6. Supplier - Minor Material: Specialty";
    var regexPattern = @"(?<number>\d+)\.\s(?<supplier>\w+)\s-\s(?<product>.+)";
    var matched = Regex.Match(myString, regexPattern);
    if (matched.Success)
    {
        var supplier = matched.Groups["supplier"].Value;
        var product = matched.Groups["product"].Value;
    }
```

Based on your requirements for Nintex, you could try the following two regular expressions, though they're far from ideal:

Matches first word after number (with lookahead and lookbehind):

```
(?<=\d\.\s).+(?=\s-\s)
```

Matches words after dash - (with lookbehind)

```
(?<=\s-\s).+
```

Comment: I just need 2 separate one liner regex. one to give me first word after a number and 2nd regex to give me everything after the dash - sign.

Comment: @Fuji-H2O, that's what this does. But it uses one regex with the results in seperate groups. Have you tried it? The value of supplier will be 'Supplier' and product value will be 'Minor Material: Specialty'

Comment: (?<=\d\.\s).+(?=\s-\s) and (?<=\s-\s).+ worked perfectly. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/e85mmj/2)

```
^\d+\.[ \t]*([^-\r\n]+?)(?:$|[ \t]*-[ \t]*(.*))
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
4. Cost/Estimating
6. Supplier - Minor Material: Specialty
6. Supplier - Pressure Vessels & Filters
6. Supplier - Pumps
6. Supplier - Minor Material: Valves
6. Supplier - Minor Material: Specialty
6. Supplier - Other Major Equipment
7. Manufacturing
8. Project Management
9. Order Release (OTR) - Commercial Documents
9. Order Release (OTR) - Hand-Off
6. Supplier - Compressors, Drivers & Refrig. Units
```

#### Output

Below output shows capture group 1 separated by the optional capture group 2. Each complete match separated by a new line.

```
Cost/Estimating

Supplier
Minor Material: Specialty

Supplier
Pressure Vessels & Filters

Supplier
Pumps

Supplier
Minor Material: Valves

Supplier
Minor Material: Specialty

Supplier
Other Major Equipment

Manufacturing

Project Management

Order Release (OTR)
Commercial Documents

Order Release (OTR)
Hand-Off

Supplier
Compressors, Drivers & Refrig. Units
```

---

### Explanation

Flags `g` (global - don't stop at first match) and `m` (multi-line - `^` matches the start of each line and `$` matches the end of each line) are used.

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally
- `[ \t]*` Match any number of spaces or tabs
- `([^-\r\n]+?)` Capture one or more characters not present in the set `-\r\n`, but as few as possible, into capture group 1
- `(?:$|[ \t]*-[ \t]*(.*))` Match either of the following

  - `$` Assert position at the end of the line
  - `[ \t]*` Match any number of spaces or tabs
  - `-` Match the hyphen character `-` literally
  - `[ \t]*` Match any number of spaces or tabs
  - `(.*)` Capture any character (except for line terminators) any number of times into capture group 2

Comment: I can't use group in Nintex which supports c# .net regex. I just need 2 separate regex. 1st regex to give me first word after a number and dot. and 2nd regex that will give me everything after the dash -. I wont use both regex at the same time. There are times when i use the first one and there are time when i just use the 2nd regex. so i just need 2 separate regex without group.